# help me understand now() for mysql current time and its time zones

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time, timezone

I need help understand how mysql can determine what the timezone is when I use the function now() (in mysql) when I insert into mysql database. The datetime format is YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00. How do you get the user to get the right time at their location?

Does this question make sense?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you referring to the php now() function or the mysql now() function. Just clarifying.

Comment: -1 there is no `now()` function in php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`now()` is always refer to the server time from its timezone.

If you have both server and user timezone,
it can be done via function [`convert_tz`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz),
such as

```
set @user_time_zone:='+02:00';
set @server_time_zone:='+08:00';

-- server timezone always come first
-- as now() is from server time
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(now(),@server_time_zone, @user_time_zone);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your datetime format `YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00` has no timezone information, so it's irrelevant which timezone the user is in.

`NOW()` uses the system's time.

Answer (score 1):

the now() function return system time  determine your server's time and location! 
mysql can not do this for u, this is your program's job!!

Answer (score 1):

The system timezone is controlled by system_time_zone variable.
you can view the current system time zone using the following in the mysql prompt

```
SELECT @@system_time_zone;
```

The system time zone can be changed using --timezone=timezone_name in the mysql server option