# MySQL-PHP get and echo NOW() value?

Tags: mysql

I need to get the current time my database is using as NOW() and show it to the user. How can I do this?

What is used as `NOW()`? Does this time and date have to do with my PHP configuration or are they unique to the database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [help me understand now() for mysql current time and its time zones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7411647/help-me-understand-now-for-mysql-current-time-and-its-time-zones)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: This is one of those things you Google (or Bing, but not Yahoo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$query  = "SELECT NOW() as `now`";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row    = $result->fetch_array();
$now    = $row['now'];
echo "$now\n";

?>
```